# How do you perform a redirect within a facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to perform a server side redirect within my facebook application but I when I do a normal redirect, facebook 404s the url (even though its valid). I'm assuming that they block traditional browser redirects (for saftey). I found fb:redirect (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/page-admin-edit-header) but I cant even get their demo to work. Is this no longer supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending down a `<fb:redirect url="target" />` to facebook works